# What is the best way to dynamically set a linked property with just their FK

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've got an entity with a lot of linked properties, when I'm handling a CSV import, I don't want to create `$em->getReference()` calls for all the linked fields (mainly because i want to keep it as abstract as possible and don't want to hard code all the possible references).

I rather want to do this in the Entity setter method for the given properties. However that would require me to access doctrine from within the Model which in its turn is a bad practice.

Should i access the entity's Metadata and go from there or is there a better approach to this, which I haven't yet mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in the setter, really messes up the whole SOA thing. If you care about the code being decoupled and abstract you can use [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).
 Let's say you have entity `A` that has associations to entity `B` and `C`, then for getting the references to correct `B` and `C` instances from the raw data you get from the `CSV`, you would define two interfaces e.g: `BRepositoryInterface` and `CRepositoryInterface`, they both might contain a single method `find($id)`, but they still have to be distinct. Now make your Doctrine Repositories for the respective entities implement these interfaces and inject them into the service where create entity `A`.
If you really wanna make some good code, then you should create separate classes implementing each of these interfaces, and then inject your Doctrine Repositories into them, these classes then act as wrappers for those repositories, this way you have a distinct layer between your `DataMapper` layer and your `business logic` layer, which gives you the abstraction you want.
This is what I've learned in my recent studies on good code, `DDD` and Design patterns. It is no where near perfect(not that there is such a thing). Any Ideas/Comments would be appreciated.

---

**Update**: In regards to your comment:
One of the main things that good design strives for is "capturing the language of domain experts", (see [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=iefGBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=capture%20the%20language%20of%20domain%20experts&source=bl&ots=Di7eJQlyQB&sig=SmanmLM1tfTBQ53WlMfmA8FVxuo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBWoVChMIqdSpwf-ixwIVw4gsCh1cUQuo#v=onepage&q=capture%20the%20language%20of%20domain%20experts&f=false) item no.4 for a description of these legendary beings).i.e: What is your code in plain English?
What your code says is basically find the Objects with these given ids from the repositories of the Entities that have an association to `A`.This looks pretty good since you have no explicit dependencies on what `A` has associations to.But looking at it closer, you'll see that you do have dependencies on actual `B` and `C` Objects and their repositories, since when you provide an **`id`** for some Object, you're not just providing an `id`, but you're also implicitly stating what that object is, otherwise an `id` would have no meaning other than it's scalar Value.However that approach definitely has it's use cases both in **Semantics** of the Design, and **RAD**.But there is still the issue of **Law of Demeter**, but it can be solved, see below:
Either way I think you should definitely have a factory for `A` objects that looks something like this.

```
class AFactory{

  protected $br;
  protected $cr;

  public function __construct(BRepositoryInterface $br, CrepositoryInterface $cr){
    $this->br = $br;
    $this->cr = $cr;
  }

  public function create($atr1, $atr2, $bId, $cId){
    $b = $this->br->find($bId);
    $c = $this->cr->find($cId);
    return new A($atr1, $atr2, $bId, $cId);
  }
}
```

Now you can actually create this factory using the design you stated by having another factory for this factory, this will also solve the issue with **Law of Demeter**.That Factory will have the `Entity Manager` as it's dependency, it will read `A`'s metadata, and fetch the Repositories of the related objects based on that metadata, and create a new `AFactory` Instance from those repositories, now if you implement those interfaces (`BRepositoryInterface` and `CRepositoryInterface`) in your actual Doctrine Repositories, the `AFactory` instance will be successfully created.

Comment: I understand your solution, it seems the best solution, would you say getting the entity's metadata and do something like the following in a service: `$em->getRepository($metadata->associationMappings[$propertyname]['targetEntity'])->find($pk);` is breaking the MVC principle / or just messy code? Or would it be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the further elaboration, this helped me a lot!